# Xcode UICollectionViewCell xib not displaying any views added to it

Tags: xcode, xib, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I'm trying to create a custom UICollectionViewCell backed by a *.xib file.
However, when I try to add subviews to the cell, interface builder (as well as an actual instance of the cell inside the app) doesn't show them at all.
It doesn't matter whether I add in an UIView as a contentView or not, all subviews seem to be invisible.
This happens in Xcode 7.2 inside a tvOS project. Does anyone experience the same issue or can see what I'm missing?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VIcdEV9.png]

Comment: Could you give more information or parts of the code?

Comment: There are no important additional aspects to it, subviews do not show even in interface builder, where no actual code is involved.

Comment: I have this issue every once in a while, i think its just an Xcode bug. Not sure if you can do anything about it.

Comment: How did you solve it? I tried everything but I can't get it to show any subviews. I could work around it by defining a separate UIView and attaching it to the cell via code, but that feels like a complete hack.

Comment: I have reported this bug to apple: rdar://24232574
Please go to https://bugreport.apple.com/ login and create a bug to bump up its priority.

Comment: Happening to me in case of xcode 7.3 as well (for both collection view cell and tableview cell). Were you able to fix it yet?